# Why does indexing a numpy array using an array change the shape?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to index a 2-dimensional array to certain values using numpy.where(), but unless I am indexing in the first index without a `:` slice it always increases the dimension. I can't seem to find an explanation for this in the documentation.

For example, say I have an array `a`:

```
a = np.arange(20)
a = np.reshape(a,(4,5))
print("a = ",a)
print("a shape = ", a.shape)
```

Output:

```
a =  [[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
a shape =  (4, 5)
```

If I have two indexing arrays, one in the 'x' direction and one in the 'y' direction:

```
x = np.arange(5)
y = np.arange(4)
xindx = np.where((x>=2)&(x<=4))
yindx = np.where((y>=1)&(y<=2))
```

and then index `a` using the 'y' index like so there's no problem:

```
print(a[yindx])
print(a[yindx].shape)
```

Output:

```
[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]]
(2, 5)
```

But if I have `:` in one of the indices then I have an extra dimension of size 1:

```
print(a[yindx,:])
print(a[yindx,:].shape)
print(a[:,xindx])
print(a[:,xindx].shape)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
  [10 11 12 13 14]]]
(1, 2, 5)
[[[ 2  3  4]]
 [[ 7  8  9]]
 [[12 13 14]]
 [[17 18 19]]]
(4, 1, 3)
```

I run into this issue with one-dimensional arrays, too. How do I fix this?

Comment: `a[yindx]` already gives a two-dimensional array, and then you add a dimension by adding the comma and colon in `a[yindx,:]` to tell numpy to give you everything in this array and everything along the third dimension as well. Its not clear what you expect to happen differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `xindx` and `yindx` were numpy arrays, the result would be as expected. However, they are tuples with a single value.

Easiest (and pretty dumb) fix:

```
xindx = np.where((x>=2)&(x<=4))[0]
yindx = np.where((y>=1)&(y<=2))[0]
```

With only the condition given, `np.where` will return indices of matching elements in a tuple. This use is explicitly discouraged in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

More realistically, you probably need something like:

```
xindx = np.arange(2, 5)
yindx = np.arange(1, 3)
```

... but it really depends on the context we don't see